# 'Years of hard work' is/are

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> All those years of hard work **have** finally paid off.

Shouldn't it be *all those years of hard work **has** finally paid off* ? *Years of hard work* is a single thing, I think.

If the prior version is correct - which probably is - then why is it 'They met again after **a** gap of twenty years.' [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gap?q=gap)

It's from the exercises on [this Web site](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-14/session-4/activity-2), the 2nd one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's referring to the years, not the hard work. "Those" is a plural pronoun and a determiner. It determines which years you are speaking about, but it doesn't group them. Saying "years of hard work" is like saying "bottles of water" - you can count bottles just like you can count years, so they are plural.

The example you are comparing it to is completely different. In "*a gap of twenty years*", the 'gap' is a singular noun.

- **A gap** of twenty years (singular)
- **A year** of hard work (singular)
- **Gaps** of twenty years (plural)
- **Years** of hard work (plural)

Answer (score 0):

The subject is "years", which is plural. You may think of the "years of hard work" as a single period of time, but grammatically, it's plural "years".

If you said, "A period of 20 years of hard work ..." that would be singular and take a singular verb like "is" or "has", because "period" is singular.